# Touchard-Like Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, partial-differential-equations, generating-functions

The sequence $\{T_n(x)\}$ of Touchard polynomials can be defined recursively through $T_n=x(1+\frac{d}{dx})T_{n-1}.$ Their exponential generating function satisfies $\sum_{n\geq 0} T_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}=e^{x(e^t-1)},$ which generate the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

I am interested in the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ with $f_0(x)=1$ and $$f_n=(1+x+x\frac{d}{dx})f_{n-1}.$$ Their generating function $F(x,t)=\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}$ can be shown to satisfy $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=(1+x)F+x\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}.$$ Here are a couple of questions I'd like help with:

1. Is the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ well-known?
2. How does one solve the PDE above?

Thanks

Comment: Though you have an accepted answer below, it really only discusses your first question. To answer the second, use the method of characteristics; the general solution is given by $$F = e^{-x + t} g(x e^{t})$$ for some arbitrary differentiable function g. You can then apply the initial condition to get $$F(x, 0) = f_{0}(x) = 1 = e^{-x} g(x) \implies g(x) = e^{x}$$ and hence $$F = e^{t} e^{x (e^{t} - 1)}$$ which is just the exponential generating function for the Touchard polynomials multiplied by $e^{t}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the Wikipedia article
[Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials)
define the differential operator
$$ L_A(f(x)) := x f(x) + x \frac{d}{dx} f(x). $$
Define the sequence of Touchard (or exponential) polynomials with
$$ T_0(x) := 1,\quad T_{n+1}(x) := L_A(T_n(x)). $$
The exponential generating function of these polynomials is
$$ A(x,t) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!} = e^{x(e^t-1)}. $$

Now, the question is asked about a variant operator
$$ L_B(f(x)) := f(x)+L_A(f(x)) = f(x)+x f(x) + x \frac{d}{dx} f(x). $$
Similarly, define a sequence of polynomials with
$$ f_0(x) := 1, \quad f_{n+1}(x) := L_B(f_n(x)). $$
Computing the first few polynomials suggests that the e.g.f.
$$ B(x,t) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!} =
   e^{t+x(e^t-1)} = e^t A(x,t) $$
which can be easily verified. Also, the relation
$\, f_n(x) = T_{n+1}(x)/x. $